# Interface Builder won't connect button, but the tutorial says it should work

Tags: objective-c, core-data, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I've been trying to learn Core Data, and browsing through questions on Stack Overflow lead me to a recommendation that I try the tutorial on Core Data over at Cocoa Dev Central ([Link](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php)).

Everything is making sense so far in the tutorial, but when I got to step 16, it wouldn't let me connect the + button to the Posts array controller.  I've gone back and double, triple-checked each step along the way and can't see where anything is off, but it still won't let me connect.  I'm using the latest versions of Xcode and Interface Builder (just re-downloaded them last week); could this be a version compatibility issue?

**Addendum**

Seems that the problem was in that I had to change the name by changing the class in the inspector, and that removed the default actions for the array controller.  Changing the class back to `NSArrayController` restores functionality, but now it appears as "Array Controller" wherever it appears, which seems like it'd become problematic with 3 controllers in play once I fix the Authors and Topics controllers.

Comment: You are Pressing the Ctrl Key, Dragging from the Button to the Posts Controller? And the posts controller does have an action on it? What is it you're seeing when you do this?

Comment: Yep, I'm control-dragging from the button to the Posts controller.  The Posts controller doesn't highlight, neither does anything appear if I drag from the controller to the button.  Simply control clicking the Posts controller doesn't show an `add:` action like I'm supposed to be linking, which I guess is the issue, but I don't see anything in the tutorial for explicitly adding it.

Comment: The posts controller should be an instance of NSArrayController - Is that the name of the type you see in the Inspector? Perhaps you've not got an NSArrayController and have got a generic controller with no actions?

Comment: Negative, the object shows as `NSArrayController` in the palette.  Icon is a green sphere with 3 blue boxes side-by-side inside.

Comment: Ok, I think I found part of the problem; when I tried to rename the controller, the only way I could do it was to go into the inspector and change "class" to "Posts", since double-clicking it was doing nothing.  Changing it back allows me to add the property, but leaves the name at the default.  Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  Under the inspector, use "Name" to change the name of the object, not "Class".  Newbie error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you changed the class of the Posts controller from an NSArrayController to a custom class called Posts. Interface builder couldn't find an implementation for this custom class, hence, did not show any actions or outlets available to bind against.

Changing the class back to NSArrayController fixed the problem.

(Interface builder lets you do this as you may want to define your own custom controller. You can add the actions and outlets to the object in IB, then generate the class and add the implementation in XCode. This is quite useful - but can confuse new users of the tool.)